# JQuery Refresh List effect - FadeOut FadeIn Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a slight issue with a `jQuery` effect I'm trying to achieve. I'd like for a list to `fadeIn` and when the user clicks a button `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` again to appear as though it is refreshing.

I've got the code in JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/javacadabra/qtppk74p/3/

Basically the `HTML` structure is as follows, 3 buttons, depending on which button is pressed decides on which `li` to display.

```
<p>Please Choose a Job Category:</p>
<div id='sales' class='jbtn'>Sales Jobs</div>
<div id='it' class='jbtn'>IT Jobs</div>
<div id='hr' class='jbtn'>HR Jobs</div>
<div id='jobs-list'>
     <h2 id='jobs-title'></h2>
    <ul id='the-jobs-list'></ul>
</div>
```

The `JQuery` checks which button is clicked and refreshes the list adding the new `li` elements.

```
$('#sales').click(function () {
    refreshList()
    $('#jobs-title').html("Sales Jobs");
    $('#the-jobs-list').append("<li>Sales Job 1</li>");
    $('#the-jobs-list').append("<li>Sales Job 2</li>");
    $('#the-jobs-list').append("<li>Sales Job 3</li>");

});
$('#it').click(function () {
    refreshList()
    $('#jobs-title').html("IT Jobs");
    $('#the-jobs-list').append("<li>IT Job 1</li>");
    $('#the-jobs-list').append("<li>IT Job 2</li>");
    $('#the-jobs-list').append("<li>IT Job 3</li>");
});
$('#hr').click(function () {
    refreshList()
    $('#jobs-title').html("HR Jobs");
    $('#the-jobs-list').append("<li>HR Job 1</li>");
    $('#the-jobs-list').append("<li>HR Job 2</li>");
    $('#the-jobs-list').append("<li>HR Job 3</li>");
});

function refreshList() {
    $('#the-jobs-list').fadeOut();
    $('#the-jobs-list').empty();
    $('#the-jobs-list').fadeIn();
}
```

At the moment I'm getting an unusual effect whereby the list items are appended and then fade out and fade back in. Ideally i'd like for the fade out to happen before the appending of the items.

If you check out my fiddle you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `fadeOut` callback.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qtppk74p/4/)

In essence, instead of letting it all run together, make sue the data is updated then faded in by doing those actions in a callback function, which fires only after fade out is done.

```
$('#the-jobs-list').fadeOut(400, function () {
    $('#the-jobs-list').empty();
    $('#jobs-title').html("Sales Jobs");
    $('#the-jobs-list').append("<li>Sales Job 1</li>");
    $('#the-jobs-list').append("<li>Sales Job 2</li>");
    $('#the-jobs-list').append("<li>Sales Job 3</li>");
    $('#the-jobs-list').fadeIn();
});
```

In [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) it's named the `complete` parameter.

Comment: Thank you for that, works perfectly, will accept answer in 4 minutes when I Can.